# How can you create a dict-like object that returns duplicate values via items()

Tags: python

### Framework

I am using the [hyper](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) framework to generate HTTP/2 traffic. When generating requests and responses, I'm currently using the [hyper.HTTP20Connection.request](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hyper.HTTP20Connection.request) and [h2.H2Connection.send_headers](https://python-hyper.org/projects/hyper-h2/en/stable/api.html#h2.connection.H2Connection.send_headers) to send HTTP/2 requests and responses, respectively.

### My Requirement

I need to be able to send HTTP/2 requests and responses with duplicated fields. Here, for example, is a YAML specified request that contains two `x-test-duplicate` fields:

```
  headers:
    fields:
    - [ :method, GET, equal ]
    - [ :scheme, https, equal ]
    - [ :authority, example.data.com, equal ]
    - [ :path, '/a/path?q=3', equal ]
    - [ Accept, '*/*' ]
    - [ Accept-Language, en-us ]
    - [ Accept-Encoding, gzip ]
    - [ x-test-duplicate, first ]
    - [ x-test-duplicate, second ]
    - [ Content-Length, "0" ]
```

Note that, per the HTTP/2 specification, this is explicitly allowed. See for example [RFC 7541 section 2.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541#section-2.3.2):

> The dynamic table can contain duplicate entries (i.e., entries with
> the same name and same value).  Therefore, duplicate entries MUST NOT
> be treated as an error by a decoder.

### My Problem

The problem is that while [h2.H2Connection.send_headers](https://python-hyper.org/projects/hyper-h2/en/stable/api.html#h2.connection.H2Connection.send_headers) properly handles an iterable of tuples that can contain duplicate fields (e.g., `(("name1", "value1"), ("name2", "value2"), ("name1", "another_value"))`), [hyper.HTTP20Connection.request](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hyper.HTTP20Connection.request) requires a dictionary which, of course, is not designed for duplicate keys. The documentation isn't clear about the type requirements upon `headers`, but in the source code for [HTTP20Connection:request, line 261](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper/blob/75f25f73c17a16cb1f2ca7d46f390b0dfe4925dc/hyper/http20/connection.py#L261), `items()` is called off of it. If I pass an iterable of tuples, I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'`. Note how sad this is: the hyper framework forces the user to pass in a dictionary, which doesn't allow duplicates, then immediately turns that dictionary into an iterable of tuples via `items()`, the latter of which would allow duplicate fields. If it just took an iterable of tuples to start with, like h2's interface, I would not have this problem.

### My Question

I filed issue [437](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper/issues/437) in the hyper github project about this limitation. In the meantime I am hoping that I can work around this problem. I have an iterable of tuples representing the HTTP/2 headers with duplicate fields. Can I somehow wrap that in an object such that when [HTTP20Connection:request, line 261](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper/blob/75f25f73c17a16cb1f2ca7d46f390b0dfe4925dc/hyper/http20/connection.py#L261) calls `items()` against it, it just returns the iterable of tuples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python typically uses an `EmailMessage` instance for this ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage)).

> The `EmailMessage` dictionary-like interface is indexed by the header names, which must be ASCII values. The values of the dictionary are strings with some extra methods. Headers are stored and returned in case-preserving form, but field names are matched case-insensitively. Unlike a real dict, there is an ordering to the keys, and there can be duplicate keys. Additional methods are provided for working with headers that have duplicate keys.

In basic usage, you would set items using [`EmailMessage.add_header`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.add_header) and retrieve them with [`EmailMessage.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.items). You may leave the payload blank.

```
>>> from email.message import EmailMessage
>>> headers = EmailMessage()
>>> headers.add_header("x-test-duplicate", "first")
>>> headers.add_header("x-test-duplicate", "second")
>>> headers.items()
[('x-test-duplicate', 'first'), ('x-test-duplicate', 'second')]
```

This is battle tested in [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) itself, which [uses the same class for HTTPResponse headers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.headers).

The advantage over rolling your own multidict or using a simple list of pairs is that you'll get the correct behavior for headers (RFC 5322 and RFC 6532 style field names and values), for example case-insensitivity:

```
>>> headers.add_header("aBc", "val1")
>>> headers.add_header("AbC", "val2")
>>> headers.get_all("ABC")
['val1', 'val2']
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. To be explicit, I've verified that this does indeed satisfy  hyper.HTTP20Connection.request() and results in duplicate fields being sent. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Since Python supports Duck Typing, a class that has an `items` method is sufficient:

```
class Wrapper:
    __slots__ = ["pairs"]  # Minor optimization
    def __init__(self, pairs: Iterable[Tuple[str, str]]):
        self.pairs = pairs

    def items(self) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, str]]:
        return self.pairs
```

Then:

```
header_pairs = [("name1", "value1"), ("name2", "value2"), ("name1", "another_value")]
wrapped = Wrapper(header_pairs)
request(method, url, body, headers=wrapped)
```

The major issue with this is it relies entirely on implementation details of `request`. If they chose in the future to use `headers` for other dict-like purposes, this will break quite easily.